# Clock Ringing/Noise

Tags: digital-logic, clock

I'm trying to make a simple 32.768kHz clock circuit.  On the [datasheet](http://www.ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/ECS-3x8X%202x6X%201X5X.pdf) for a crystal that I found, it included the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8eNFH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, when I implemented the circuit, the edges are 'noisy', they contain sinusoidal ringing.

[image: Yellow = CLK, Pink = inverted CLK]

[image: Zoomed edge]

Is there any way to tweak the resistor or the capacitor values to eliminate the ringing?

Comment: To what kind of sink is the clock signal connected? Maybe you have a mismatch here.

Comment: Does your inverter have a Schmitt trigger??

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered, but the answer seems to have disappeared.  The problem stemmed from using a *buffered* inverter, along with implementing the circuit on a breadboard.  Switching to an unbuffered inverter and implementing on perfboard fixed the waveform.

Comment: What do you mean by 'buffered'?

Comment: @m.Alin: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scha004/scha004.pdf